# Kind of "soft link" of objects between scenes?

Tags: linked-data, scene

I want to reuse the object of one scene in another. So far, I found two possibilities, both with side effects I do not want:

1. Copy and paste from one scene to another. However, if I'll edit / correct the mesh in the first scene, I do not see the changes in the second scene.
2. Linking from one scene to another. This reflects the mesh changes, but also rotational changes. If I rotate the object in the second scene to lay it on the floor for presentational purposes, it also rotates in the first scene, where I actually want it to just stand around for modelling it.

Is there some kind of soft link which reflect mesh changes, but not rotational / position / scale ones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the 2nd method, linking your object to the other scene.

Link the object to the other scene as normal. Selecting that object (the one you want to be able to rotate but still be linked) navigate to it's 'Object' tab in the 'Properties' window and make it's object datablock a single user by clicking the '2':

[image]

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>U</kbd>> Object to achieve the same effect, which will make any of the selected objects a single user.

Clicking the '2' makes a copy of the transformational data for the object but leaves the mesh data, the vertices and faces etc as linked, as shown in the 'data' tab:

[image]

The '2' shows that the data is now being used by 2 distinct objects, with different transformations, whereas before it was acting as a single object, sharing both transformations and data.

Comment: Awesome! Do you know if it is also possible to automatically apply this change to all child objects? I had one child this time and had to do the step of creating a transform data copy twice, once for the parent, once for the child.

Comment: I added a bit more info under the second picture, which will make any of the selected objects a single user, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Yep, that was it :) thx