# Cannot save object renderability in a scene?

Tags: rendering

As a beginner in Blender, I think my outliner is telling me I have two scenes.

[image]

First I only modified renderability in `comp`, but I realized I need to change renderability in `5.2` too. So I made all `Butterfly*` objects (not sure if it's the right word) not to be rendered. Then I saved my Blender file.

However, when I reopened the file, the renderability options have switched back. Why can't I save my renderability settings in scence `5.2`?

Comment: In general you shouldn't have possibility to change something with those objects from the scene "5.2" because the whole scene appears to be linked. The linked data isn't actually in the current file, it's in the library. So probably renderability wasn't even changed before saving.

Comment: @MrZak But is there a way to modify the "library"? It's really a pain to toggle renderability all over again every time I close the application. Also I need to change parameters of the camera that appears in the "library". Thanks!

Comment: Either toggle it in their origin library-blendfile, or make the objects local in your current file so those settings may correctly be saved there too.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5664/how-can-i-modify-the-mesh-of-a-linked-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects in scene "5.2" won't let you change their options because the whole scene which they are part of is linked. This can be detected by small white sign with an arrow just next to the linked object or any datablock:

[image: screenshot of linked scene outliner]

It's all about the [linking data](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html) in Blender. The library is a .blend file located somewhere else (but Blender knows where it is as it can read the data from that file) where that data is stored. To edit those objects you can either:

- edit those objects only from the file they were created in.
- make a local copy of the objects.

The first way assumes you will continously switch between the different .blend files - change some options in the main .blend (where the object / group / some other useful data is stored), then return back to .blend where objects are imported to (e.g. for rendering), change their locations, etc., etc.
However the structure will be organized - all the data will be stored in its own files and only uneditable entities will be stored in the working file (which is sometimes preferred).
This may be possible with using some addons, like [Edit Linked Library](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Edit_Linked_Library) and so on. For more info refer to [How can I modify the mesh of a linked character?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5664/how-can-i-modify-the-mesh-of-a-linked-character)

The second way will let you edit any mesh or object, change it properties, edit everything about it - but full editable copies of these objects will be present in every file, with all the consequences (every file will occupy much more space; meshes might get changes assumed for one project which is undesired for another project etc).
See [Change linked object to appended?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46945/change-linked-object-to-appended) and [Kind of "soft link" of objects between scenes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27046/kind-of-soft-link-of-objects-between-scenes)